# how to use icons with Mui Joy?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just started working with the new library JOY by MUI.
once I needed icons I import the @mui icons library and I got a bunch of errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/esm/ZoomOutTwoTone.js 3:15-28
export 'default' (imported as 'createSvgIcon') was not found in './utils/createSvgIcon' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/esm/utils/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/feuersteiner/dev/third-lean-mean/node_modules/@mui/material/esm/utils/index.js'
```

what I did was pretty basic, here's the file :

```js
import { Phone } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Box, ListItemDecorator, Tab, TabList, Tabs } from "@mui/joy";

function MyPage() {
  return (
    <Box width="100wh" height="100vh" bgcolor={"red"}>
      <Tabs orientation="vertical">
        <TabList variant="soft" color="neutral">
          <Tab>
            <ListItemDecorator>
              <Phone />
            </ListItemDecorator>
            Favorite
          </Tab>
          <Tab>test</Tab>
          <Tab>test</Tab>
        </TabList>
      </Tabs>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default MyPage;
```

Comment: Hello, please share the related part of your code so that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: just updated the question, feel free to check the code

Comment: I would say the first issue is you don't have that dependency installed. Run the command `npm install`

Comment: I did, I tried installing emotion, styled, mui-core, mui utils, deleted both lock and modules ... still same error